# Convert nested list to dict where first element of list is key for dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have list ,

```
[['1', '4.00', 'A'],
['1', '5.00', 'B'],
['2', '4.00', 'V'],
['1', '12.00', 'C'],
['3', '4.00', 'R']]
```

How can I convert this list to,

```
{'1': [{'total': 21}, {'data': [['A'], ['B'], ['C']]}]}
{'2': [{'total': 4}, {'data': ['C']}]}
{'3':....}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all we sort the data which would sort the nested lists based upon the initial elements and hence we get nested list with the elements sorted on the first index of list inside the nested list, then we simply [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) them on the first element.

```
import itertools

a= [['1', '4.00', 'A'],
   ['1', '5.00', 'B'],
   ['2', '4.00', 'V'],
   ['1', '12.00', 'C'],
   ['3', '4.00', 'R'],
]

a.sort()

dictionary = {}
group = itertools.groupby(a, key = lambda x:x[0])
for k,g in group:
   ans = 0
   alphabets = []
   for i in g:
      ans+=(float(i[1]))
      alphabets.append([i[2]])
   dictionary[k] = [{'total':ans}, {'date':alphabets}]

print dictionary

>>> {'1': [{'total': 21.0}, {'date': [['C'], ['A'], ['B']]}], '3': [{'total': 4.0}, {'date': [['R']]}], '2': [{'total': 4.0}, {'date': [['V']]}]}
```